# Member must have length less than or equal to 6; Value

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, multi-factor-authentication

I'm running this command:

```
 aws ecr get-login-password --region <YOUR_REGION> | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin  <ACCOUNT_ID>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com
```

After I enter the 6 digit AWS MFA Token I'm getting this error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the AssumeRole operation: 2 validation errors detected: Value '�I�O�G�O�H�K' at 'tokenCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 6; Value '�I�O�G�O�H�K' at 'tokenCode' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\d]*
> Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1):

I feel really silly, the command window input doesn't show the password/mfa characters you type.

I was using the NumPad keys and NumLock was enabled! So I was entering a blank token...